# Getting event from buttons generated by for loop in wxpython

Tags: sqlite, wxpython

Good day @all. I hope your day was great? I also really want to thank everyone that contributed toward helping me solved the problem I had when I posted last time.
Today, I have a problem and it has to do with bunch of buttons I had th almighty for loop generate for me. The buttons will be generated along side labels like this: For student A => nameof_studentA_label, Scoreof_studentA and the end of the row the button
=> nameof_studentB_label, Scoreof_studentB and the end of the row the button.
.......
Trouble is I couldn't get get their event to work. To be specific, whenever I clicked any of the button apart from the first button I don't get any action.

What I wanted doing is to fetch rows of record from an sqlite database and display the fields and a button with the label "Display Record" event will call a method I named "view_student_exam_record" and somehow get the info that matches the info from the database that were matched to the button. The event will fire after I clicked on any of the for-loop-generated-loop.

Below is the code that fetch the record and generate the labels and button using for loop.

```
def search_exam_record(self, event):
        count=0
        if self.search_exam_class_name_text.GetValue()!="" and self.search_exam_term_name_text.GetValue()!="" and self.search_exam_session_name_text.GetValue()!="":
            #search_exam_record = SchoolManagementSystem.retrieve_data(SchoolManagementSystem, "exam", "*", "where class=? and term =? and session=?", (self.search_exam_class_name_text.GetValue().lower(), self.search_exam_term_name_text.GetValue(), self.search_exam_session_name_text.GetValue()))
            search_exam_record=cursor.execute("select *, rank() over(order by total_scores desc) as rank from exam where class=? and term=? and session=? ", (self.search_exam_class_name_text.GetValue().lower(), self.search_exam_term_name_text.GetValue(), self.search_exam_session_name_text.GetValue()))
            
            self.sub_dict = {}
            count_list = []
            self.student_name_list = []
            self.student_id_list = []
            self.total_score_list = []
            self.average_list = []
            self.rank_list = []
            self.view_button_list = []
            self.button_id = []
            for exam_record in search_exam_record:
                
                student_name = exam_record['studentname']
                studentid = exam_record['student_id']
                subject_dict_str = exam_record['scores']
                
                subject_dict = eval(subject_dict_str)
                self.subject_list = list(subject_dict.keys())
                
                self.subject_score_list = list(subject_dict.values())
                total_score= exam_record['total_scores']
                rank = exam_record['rank']
                rank = str(rank)
                average_score = total_score/len(subject_dict)
                average_score = round(average_score, 2)
                if rank[-1]=='1':
                    rank = rank+'st'
                elif rank[-1]=='2':
                    rank = rank+'nd'
                elif rank[-1] =='3':
                    rank = rank+'rd'
                else:
                    rank = rank+'th'
                self.button_id.append(wx.NewId())
                name_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="Name")
                id_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="Student Id")
                total_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="Total Score")
                average_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="Average")
                position_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="Position")
                empty_heading = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label="")
                studentname_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=student_name)
                studentid_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=str(studentid))
                student_total_scores = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=subject_dict_str)
                totalscore_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=str(total_score))
                average_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=str(average_score))
                rank_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel2, label=rank)
                self.view_button = wx.Button(self.panel2, self.button_id[count], label="Display Record")
                self.student_name_list.append(studentname_label)
                self.student_id_list.append(studentid_label)
                self.total_score_list.append(totalscore_label)
                self.average_list.append(average_label)
                self.rank_list.append(rank_label)
                
                count_list.append(count)
                
                self.view_button_list.append(self.view_button)
                self.button_id.append(self.view_button_list[count].GetId())
                self.view_button_list[count].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda event, count=count: self.view_student_exam_record(event, count, self.sub_dict))
                self.sub_dict[self.view_button_list[count].GetId()]:[count+1, studentid_label.GetLabel(), studentname_label.GetLabel(), totalscore_label.GetLabel(), average_label.GetLabel(), rank_label.GetLabel() ]
            
                if count==0:
                            
                            self.search_exam_result_grid_sizer.AddMany(
                                [
                                    (name_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (id_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (total_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (average_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (position_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (empty_heading, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    

                                    (studentname_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (studentid_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (totalscore_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (average_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (rank_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    (self.view_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                ]
                                )
                        
                else:
                    
                            
                            self.search_exam_result_grid_sizer.AddMany(
                                    [
                                        (studentname_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                        (studentid_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                        (totalscore_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                        (average_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                        (rank_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                        (self.view_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                                    ]
                                )
                            

                    
            count+=1
            
            
            
        else:
            print("Please fill the required field")
        self.panel2.SetSizer(self.search_exam_result_grid_sizer)
        print(len(self.sub_dict))
```

And below is the code that get the event fired from the for-loop-generated-button

```
def view_student_exam_record(self, event, index, sub_dict):
        button_id = event.GetEventObject()
        button_id = button_id.GetId()
        print(button_id)
        counter=0
        search_student_record=cursor.execute("select student_id, dob, parentaddress, gender, place, lgaoforigin, stateoforigin, nationality, parent, passportdir from student where student_id=? ", (index,))
        print(index)
        search_student_exam_record=cursor.execute("select student_id, scores, total_scores, class, term, session from exam where student_id=? ", (index,))
        for student_record in search_student_record:
            counter+1
            student_id = student_record['student_id']
            print(student_id)
            student_dob = student_record['dob']
            
            student_gender = student_record['gender']
            student_town_village = student_record['place']
            student_lga = student_record['lgaoforigin']
            student_state = student_record['stateoforigin']
            student_nationality = student_record['nationality']
            parent = student_record['parent']
            passportfolder = student_record['passportdir']
            studentname_label =  wx.StaticText(self, label=self.student_name_list[index].GetLabel())
            studentid_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.student_id_list[index].GetLabel()))
            studentdob_label =  wx.StaticText(self, label=student_dob)
            studentgender_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=student_gender)
            studenttown_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=student_town_village)
            studentlga_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=student_lga)
            studentstate_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=student_state)
            studentnationality_label =  wx.StaticText(self, label=student_nationality)
            parent_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=parent)
            self.right_grid_box.AddMany(
                [
                 (studentname_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentid_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentdob_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentgender_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studenttown_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 #(studenttown_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentlga_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentstate_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (studentnationality_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (parent_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 
                 
            
                ]

                )
        print(index)
        self.sub_lis = []
        if len(search_student_exam_record.fetchall())>0:
            pass
        else:
            pass
        print(search_student_exam_record.fetchall())
        
        sub_index=0
        for subject in self.subject_list:
            
            subject_label =  wx.StaticText(self, label=self.subject_list[sub_index])
            test1_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.subject_score_list[sub_index][0]))
            test2_label =  wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.subject_score_list[sub_index][1]))
            test3_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.subject_score_list[sub_index][2]))
            exam_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.subject_score_list[sub_index][3]))
            total_exams_score_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.subject_score_list[sub_index][4]))
            total_score_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.total_score_list[sub_index].GetLabel()))
            average_score_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=str(self.average_list[sub_index].GetLabel()))
            position_label = wx.StaticText(self, label=self.rank_list[sub_index].GetLabel())
            self.right_grid_box2.AddMany(
                [
                 (subject_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (test1_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (test2_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (test3_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (exam_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (total_exams_score_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (total_score_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (average_score_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
                 (position_label, 0, wx.ALL, 5),
            
                ]

                )
            sub_index+=1
        self.SetSizer(self.right_box_sizer)
```

I hope I am clearn enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple app to show the principle. You need to assign an *id* to every button and you can retrieve it in the bound event using *event.GetEventObject().GetId()*

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Title = 'Wx App'

        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # One button for each student
        for index in range(5):
            button = wx.Button(self, label=f'Button {index}', id=index)
            button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.get_record)
            sizer.Add(button)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def get_record(self, event):
        print(event.GetEventObject().GetId())
        # Do your database lookup here


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Or indeed,

for i in range(5):
    id = wx.NewIdRef()
    print(id)

Comment: Thanks Psionman your code work. But when I try changing my code in a manner you have written yours by creating the id using the variable gotten from iterating through the range function, The button still behave the same way. It is only the first button that that seems to responds to the event action, after I clicked the buttons.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits your problem - we do not need to wade through all your labels, lists and grids. You might surprise yourself: cutting away the irrelevant often makes the solution clear

Comment: This is what I have done so far. I created a list variable to  store some labels, so that I can get the label value . ``` self.student_id_list=[]``` and here is where I append the labels ```self.student_id_list.append(studentid_label) ```.  Here is where I made some modification to the function self.view_student_exam_record as you suggesteed but still it didn't work. ``` def view_student_exam_record(self, event,  stud_id_list):
        button_id = event.GetEventObject().GetId()```

Comment: Okay will go back to my original post and cut out the unnecessary stuff and just make sure I present something brief.